# How to access as functions in kivy + python

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to create an app for student presence control and I'm not getting access to a function inside a class in python.

I have tried in many ways without success.

arq.py

```
class Tela(ScreenManager):
    pass
class Chamada(Screen):
    def chamada_func(self):
        self.ids.grid.add_widget(Label(text = 'teste')) 
        #I would like to press the call button, add the grid label

class Nota(Screen):
    pass
class Prg(App):
    def build(self):
        self.Chamada = Chamada()
        return Tela()

Prg().run()
```

arq.kv

```
<Tela>:
    Screen:
        name: 'Principal'
        BoxLayout:
            id: box_principal
            orientation: 'vertical'
            padding: 50
            spacing: 100
            Button:
                text: 'Chamada'
                on_release: root.current = 'Chamada'
            Button:
                text: 'Nota'
                on_release: root.current = 'Nota'   
            Button:
                text: 'Sair'
    Chamada:
        name: 'Chamada'
        BoxLayout:
            id: box_chamada
            orientation: 'vertical'
            GridLayout:
                id: grid
```

Comment: Please update **your post** to provide [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex) and indicate from where you want to invoke the method, `chamada_func()` (including the missing button)?

Answer (score 0):

## Question 2

> use this on a button inside the  class: how would it be?

### Solution 2: kv file - Invoke a method from the class that implemented it

The following solution illustrates how to invoke the method, `chamada_func()` implemented in `class Chamada()` from another children within the class via kv file.

```
        on_release: root.chamada_func()
```

#### Snippets

```
<Chamada>:
    name: 'Chamada'

    BoxLayout:
        id: box_chamada
        orientation: 'vertical'

        GridLayout:
            id: grid

        Button:
            text: 'ok'
            size_hint: 1, 0.05
            on_release: root.chamada_func()
```

## Question 1

> How to access a function?

### Solution 1: kv file - Invoke a method from another class / screen

The following solution illustrates how to invoke the method, `chamada_func()` implemented in `class Chamada()` from another class / screen in kv file.

- Add an `id: chamada` to screen, `Chamada:`
- Invoke method with `on_release: root.ids.chamada.chamada_func()`
- Remove `self.Chamada = Chamada()` from `build()` method because you don't want two instances of object, `Chamada`. On top of that, the instance instantiated in the kv file will have a view / presentation, while the other one instantiated in the `build` method does not have a view.
- In kv file, add a *class rule*, `<Chamada>:`

#### Snippets

main.py

```
class Tela(ScreenManager):
    pass

class Chamada(Screen):
    def chamada_func(self):
        self.ids.grid.add_widget(Label(text = 'teste')) 


class Nota(Screen):
    pass


class Prg(App):
    def build(self):
        return Tela()

Prg().run()
```

kv file

```
<Tela>:
    Screen:
        name: 'Principal'
        BoxLayout:
            id: box_principal
            orientation: 'vertical'
            padding: 50
            spacing: 100
            Button:
                text: 'Chamada'
                on_release: 
                    root.ids.chamada.chamada_func()
                    root.current = 'Chamada'
            Button:
                text: 'Nota'
                on_release: root.current = 'Nota'   
            Button:
                text: 'Sair'
    Chamada:
        id: chamada

<Chamada>:
    name: 'Chamada'

    BoxLayout:
        id: box_chamada
        orientation: 'vertical'

        GridLayout:
            id: grid

        Button:
            text: 'ok'
            size_hint: 1, 0.05
            on_release: root.chamada_func()
```

Comment: It helped me a lot, but I still have a question. For me to use this on a button inside the <call> class:
how would it be?

Comment: Please refer to updated post for details in regards to calling the method, `chamada_func()` from another children within the `class Chamada()` via kv file.

Comment: Dude, thanks a lot, it was exactly what I wanted to do. big hug.

Comment: [If you want to say "thank you", vote on or accept that person's answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)